# Modeling planet rotations (time of day, obliqueness, etc.)

Tags: orbit, solar-system, rotation

I created this solar system model using POV-Ray:

[image]

by following these instructions:

https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/aprx_pos_planets.pdf

The next thing I want to do is orient/rotate each globe correctly according to the time of day, time of year, obliqueness, position in its orbit, etc. but cannot find any instructions on the JPL website. How can I go about completing this task? Thanks.

**Part Two**

[deleted]

**Part Three**

So, *α* (right ascension), *δ* (declination) and *W* are Euler rotation angles. But what are the starting conditions before applying these rotations? Should the North Pole of the planet be aligned with the z-axis? Should the plane formed by the prime meridian be perpendicular to the y-axis?

Also, which axes do I rotate around, and in what order? I am guessing *δ* should be rotated first around the y-axis, then *α* around the z-axis. But *W* also looks like it should go around the z-axis. I am confused.

**Part Four**

I found another PDF document which on page 27 gives an equation for *δ*, *α* and *W*. (Not sure how to reproduce it here.)

https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/bitstream/11303/6237/4/burmeister_steffi.pdf

I *think* that according to that PDF file I need to rotate around the z-axis by W, around the x-axis by (90-δ), and around the z-axis again by (90+α), in that order. Lastly, an additional rotation (around the x-axis?) by 23.43928 degrees must be done to get the body out of the ICRF frame and into the ecliptic frame.

But I still don't know the starting conditions. I.e. before applying the transformations, should the globe's North Pole point upward? Should the intersection of the Prime Meridian and Equator lie along the x-axis? Or, am I totally wrong, and should I perform the inverse matrix calculations instead? So far I have not gotten results that match what I see in Celestia for the same Julian Date.

**Part Five**

In some instances I am able to get "close" results using the above method. In others not. For instance, Mars, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune are "close" to correct. (At least, the poles - the blue arrows - are pointing in the same directions.) The Earth is not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The *correct* results are the ones in the larger Celestia program window. My current POV-Ray results are in the smaller window to the left. The dark arrows indicate the parent (ecliptic) reference frame. The bright arrows indicate the body reference frame. The view in all images is from the top down on to the ecliptic plane.

Comment: http://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Docs/WGCCRE/WGCCRE2009reprint.pdf may or may not be helpful

Comment: That document has a lot of useful tables, but I am not sure in what order and manner to use them. There are not step-by-step instructions like the orbital elements document I linked to.

Comment: I haven't really looked deeply into that document, but it should tell you how the "0 degree longitude" line is defined for each entity, and a reference time when that 0 degree longitude pointed towards the vernal equinox. That should be enough information to compute the orientation at any time.

Comment: Can you recommend some good keywords to continue my search? I am only getting results that are indirectly related.

Comment: "orientation" is the only one I can think of. You might also see how stellarium, celestia, skyfield, and other astronomy programs/libraries handle this issue. I want to say it's a relatively new field, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Things like https://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/interactive-sky-watching-tools/mars-which-side-is-visible/ may help too. Questions like "which side of x is visible" may help. For our moon, this has been computed to great accuracy, not sure about other planets/moons

Comment: I found that "rotational parameters" (must be in quotes!) got some better results. I'm still confused about how (and when) to change back and forth between ecliptic coordinates (in my first image above), J2000 frame (in my second image above), "body-fixed reference frame", etc

Comment: Use [SPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html). It has [planetary constant kernels](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/19_pck.pdf) that describe the orientation of the planets, several moons, and a few asteroids with respect to the ICRF (or J2000; SPICE ignores the very small sub arc second difference between ICRF and J2000) as functions of time.

Comment: I would need to rewrite all those (many megabytes) scripts in POV-Ray SDL. A noble effort, but not one I'm willing to make at this time.

Comment: If you have (or can put) them on github, I could take a look, no promises. I'm guessing the scripts could be modified in a uniform way, and the work could thus be automated.

Comment: Thanks. The source code is located here: http://lib.povray.org/searchcollection/index2.php?objectName=SolarSystemOrrery&contributorTag=SharkD